# How to add hyperlink in pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I want to add a hyperlink in PDF created using `PDFBOX`, such that i click on some text example 'Click here' will redirect to URL. I tried using `PDAnnotationLink` and `PDActionURI`, but how to add it in `contentstream`?

```
PDBorderStyleDictionary borderULine = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
borderULine.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
txtLink.setBorderStyle(borderULine);
txtLink.setColour(colourBlue);

// add an action
PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI();
action.setURI("www.google.com");
txtLink.setAction(action);

contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(400, y-30);
contentStream.drawString(txtLink);----error
contentStream.endText();
```

Comment: Any idea of how to add the "Click Here" to the link?

Comment: Just a side note, If we add text `https://www.google.com` to content stream, it will be automatically considered as link and will be clickable inside PDF. May be useful to someone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add to `contentStream` use the following code

```
    PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
    position.setLowerLeftX(10);
    position.setLowerLeftY(20); 
    position.setUpperRightX(100); 
    position.setUpperRightY(10); 
    txtLink.setRectangle(position);
    page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
```

Comment: This is not adding something to the content stream, but annotations are not part of the content stream...

Comment: So if I'm getting this right, in order to add a link you'll need to add an annotation, with an action that will be positioned on a text held by the content stream?

Answer (score 5):

This is a fully working example, tested with PDFBox 2.0.19:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionURI;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationLink;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDBorderStyleDictionary;

public class MainCreateHyerLink
{
  public static void main (final String [] args) throws Exception
  {
    try (final PDDocument doc = new PDDocument ())
    {
      final PDPage page = new PDPage (new PDRectangle (250, 150));
      doc.addPage (page);

      try (final PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream (doc, page))
      {
        final PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink ();

        // border style
        final PDBorderStyleDictionary linkBorder = new PDBorderStyleDictionary ();
        linkBorder.setStyle (PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
        linkBorder.setWidth (10);
        txtLink.setBorderStyle (linkBorder);

        // Border color
        final Color color = Color.GREEN;
        final float [] components = new float [] { color.getRed () / 255f, color.getGreen () / 255f, color.getBlue () / 255f };
        txtLink.setColor (new PDColor (components, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));

        // Destination URI
        final PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI ();
        action.setURI ("https://www.helger.com");
        txtLink.setAction (action);

        // Position
        final PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle ();
        position.setLowerLeftX (10);
        position.setLowerLeftY (10);
        position.setUpperRightX (200);
        position.setUpperRightY (10 + 2 + 10 + 2);
        txtLink.setRectangle (position);
        page.getAnnotations ().add (txtLink);

        // Main page content
        contentStream.beginText ();
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset (12, 12);
        contentStream.setFont (PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD, 10);
        contentStream.showText ("This is linked to the outside world");
        contentStream.endText ();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. 2 lines are missing: 
contentStream.close();  doc.save(filePath);

Comment: `PDPageContentStream` implements `AutoClosable` so `contentStream.close();` is automatically called in the try-with-resources block

Answer (score 4):

There is a library called [PDFBox-Layout](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout) which makes it [easier to add hyperlinks](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout/wiki/Hyperlinks):

```
Document document = new Document();

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.addMarkup(
   "This is a link to {link[https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout]}PDFBox-Layout{link}",
 18f, BaseFont.Helvetica);
document.add(paragraph);

final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("link.pdf");
document.save(outputStream);
```

Comment: How to add the link to an existing pdf file? Using "PDDocument" object.

Comment: @NicuVlad it seems you have to load the existing PDF as background. See [github issue #69](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout/issues/69)

Comment: Shouldn't this be on the official library already? It got multiple updates so far...