# Create an external link with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

Currently, I am generating pdf files with java PDFBox library.
I want to create a text link which open another PDF on clicking.
(I know how to create the text link, but not how to link it to another file)

Can someone tell me how to do that please ? I didn't find an example.

Thank you by advance !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021502/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-pdf-using-pdfbox

Comment: Thank you guys. I was thinking this method worked only for web uri's. It works !