# How to insert a url in pdf using pdfbox with tag "click here" for redirection to website?

Tags: url, pdfbox

I am trying to give a "click here" tag in pdf using pdfbox in java but not able to understand how to do this. I have done this using iText library Anchor tag but want to do this with pdfbox.

Comment: Please have a look at the AddAnnotations.java example in the source code download.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add hyperlink in pdf using pdfbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021502/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-pdf-using-pdfbox)